# Boolean affect UV

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv

[image]
I use substance painter to paint textures and apply it into blender. Everything was good until I use boolean modifier to punch a hole. The punching hole process is an animation, so I cannot use another method. How to remain UV while having a boolean modifier?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Blender are you using ? There was abug fixed related to this issue https://developer.blender.org/T59304

This works perfectly fine with 2.92 for example as animated elements.

[image]

Comment: I use 2.90. I think found the solution, I need to use the "Exact" solver to get it right here. But this make the computation so heavy! Every moves take 5-10 sec to response and it is a pain.